# Add Appendix with correct page to ToC

Tags: table-of-contents, page-breaking, page-numbering, appendices

I am failing to add a heading for the appendix to the ToC with the correct page number:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{test}
\appendix
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\appendixname}
\chapter{First Appendix}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I also tried to use the `\addappheadtotoc` command from the [appendix](http://ctan.org/pkg/appendix) package, but that changes nothing (expect that it writes 'Appendices' instead).

I assume that the `appendix` package provides the solution, but I could not figure out how to use it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`\appendix` only changes the chapter numbering to `Alph`; it doesn't add a page break. Solution: Add `\cleardoublepage` before `\appendix`. (This is appropriate for a document using the `openright` class option; for `openany`, use `\clearpage`.)

EDIT: Personally, I wouldn't add a "pseudo chapter" to the ToC that doesn't correspond to an existing chapter (there is no chapter called "Appendix" in your example). Consider to add an unnumbered "Appendix" part to the main text and the ToC instead.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{test}
\cleardoublepage
\appendix
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\appendixname}
\chapter{First Appendix}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Indeed, with the package it would be required to use the environment `appendices` to achieve the same.

Comment: BTW: You may add `\csname phantomsection\endcsname` before the `\addcontentsline` to get correct links if you'll use package `hyperref` some day.

Comment: since `\chapter` usually invokes `\clear[double]page`, putting the `\addcontentsline` *after* the `\chapter` command would avoid having to invoke the manual page break.  of course, when `hyperref` is used, that would position the link below the appendix title.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: This would put "Appendix" *after* "A. First Appendix" in the ToC.

Comment: @lockstep -- okay, thanks.  i was misreading that, and assumed rashly that the `\addcontentsline` was there for the purpose of putting in the entry for the appendix itself.  on the other hand, my preference (based at least partly on ams practice) is to omit the page number from a "part" heading in the t-of-c.  ymmv.