# How can I add the Appendix to the tables of content?

Tags: table-of-contents, appendices

I'm using the `appendix` package and the following lines in LaTeX:

```
\begin{appendix}
\section{Supplementary Figures and Tables}
\section{Selected Derivations and Proofs} 
\end{appendix}
```

This yields to the following entry in the tables of content:

- Supplementary Figures and Tables   XI
- Selected Derivations and Proofs    XII

However, it would be nice to have something of the following form in the tables of content:

Appendix

- Supplementary Figures and Tables   XI
- Selected Derivations and Proofs    XII

So basically, I would like to have the title Appendix to show up in the tables of content but without a page number.

Comment: `\addappheadtotoc` But of course this depends on other stuff, like the documentclass.

Comment: @Johannes_B: This is surely a dupe?

Comment: Look at e.g. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/172496/adding-appendix-chapters-without-sections-in-table-of-contents

Comment: Dupe : [Add Appendix with correct page to ToC](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/37537)